# Web.Config Error While running asp.net website on Mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have developed a website in asp.net and hosted it on server. It works fine with computer's but it do not run on mobile. The web.config error occurs every time.[Web.config Error Occurs Every Time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2pqp.jpg)

Comment: please check the answer ..you need to set that information in your web config

Comment: please do accept/upvote answer if it works for you

Comment: That's not a "web.config error". You got an error, the details of which you can't see due to your web.config settings. It quite clearly tells you what to do to modify your web.config so you can see the error details. Did you bother reading it?

Comment: @Asad - welcome please dont forget to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

In Web.Config file do as below

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

it for the Un-handeled exception thrown when use browsing your web application. if you dont set that flag user will receive full stackstrace of error which user dont want. so it better you set the flag to On or Remoteonly in production environment.

- On-Specifies that custom errors are enabled. If no defaultRedirect attribute is specified, users see a generic error. The custom errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
- Off-Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.
- RemoteOnly-Specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host. This is the default value.

Read more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sir i am new to asp.net, so please can you specify that what lines should I add in web.config file?

Comment: @Asad - i added lines ..can you please update same in your web.config file that is there in your solution ...please locate it and update it